# Getting an error when wanting to use Threading in php

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I looked into using threadings in php but it stumbled upon the error mesagge `Class Thread not found in`. Now I have looked on the internet what the problem could be and I have did the following things

- Looking at my PHP Extension Build which is `API20180731,TS,VC15` and all of the downloads in this website https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/ are VC14 and bellow so that should be no problem if i'm correct. I also looked if Threat safety was enabled and it was
- I have added `pthreadVC2.dll` to the `php/php7.3.12` file. I also have added `php_pthreads.dll` to the `ext` and I have added this to `apache\apache2.4.41`
- I also added `extension=php_pthreads.dll` to the php.ini file. (don't know if it matters where I have put it)

but I still get the same error. I restarted the server and even my pc but nothing worked

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `pthreadVC2.dll` also needs to be in the `apache\apachex.y.z\bin` folder

Comment: But never in the windows folder, WAMPServer is so flexible, this will shoot you in the foot later

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah I know that's what I meant with `and I have added this to apache`. sorry if wasn't clear enough

Comment: @RiggsFolly and I have deleted the windows part

Comment: Ok, there are also incompatabilities in various versions of pthreads related to compiler version used by the people that build the threading dll's and the one used to build PHP and Apache. You will have to check which version works properly with the WAMPServer PHP you are using. This may be a trial and error test

Comment: @RiggsFolly the weird thing is it is asking for a Class 'Threat'. I don't know if that has to do with the compiler versions but i'll try it out. I first thought like I had to add an include to my index.php :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly quick question where do I program the threading? can i do this in my www folder or does it have to be somewhere else?